# How do I create a 1-bit full adder that outputs a 2-bit sum?

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture, adder, binary, summing

I am trying to build a 1-bit full adder that outputs a 2-bit sum.

I know that the standard 1-bit FA outputs a 1-bit sum and a carry bit, but I was wondering how can I modify the FA such that the carry bit output is discarded and the only output is a 2-bit sum.

Comment: Does the carry bit not just become the highest bit of your 2 bit sum?

Comment: @KH Yes, but if the carry bit is the highest bit, it means that if I merge the carry and a 1 sum bit into a 2-bit number, the result is 11, when the result should be 10 (2).

Comment: For input 0 0, output 0 carry 0 > 00.  For input 1 0, output 1 carry 0 > 01.  For input 0 1, output 1 carry 0 > 01.  For input 1 1, output 0 carry 1 > 10.  Where is the missing case?

Comment: @KH Got it, thanks for the quick response :D

Comment: I'd write you an answer but I don't actually know how a full adder works.  I only know how it must work to do what it says it does.  And now I've looked up a full adder and it appears you have an additional carry in input, so taking that into account 11 is a possible output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could feed the carry bit to another full adder that has zeroes on its other two inputs, but that seems kind of pointless because it will just get you a copy of the carry bit.

**The carry bit is the second bit.**

If you don't need a carry input you can just use a half adder.

Answer (score 4):

So I looked up what constitutes a full adder and found its truth table.

Taken from wikipedia:

[image]

So you can see that if the adder has the correct output, your sum and carry bits are simply the 2 bit number you want.  So I guess all the full adder really does is add up to 3 binaries at a time instead of 2.